# jQuery response headers asp.net

Tags: jquery, header, response

I am trying to process a form submission via an AJAX call, my code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     url: "https://somedomain.com/signup.aspx",
     dataType: "text/html",
     success: function(output, status, xhr) {

          alert('Success!');

     },
     error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {

          alert(request.getResponseHeader('location'));

     }

});
```

Using developer tools in Chrome I can see the reponse which I am expecting in the 'Location' header. I am trying to access this data but the repsonse it always null!

Interestingly the the success part of the ajax call never happens, always the error, but the data I need is in the header so I can apply my own logic in order to do what I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Massive clue in your own text: **...the success part of the ajax call never happens...** - that is your entire problem.  You should investigate that, and get your call working properly, then you can anticipate / handle the response as intended.  Is the url you are hitting on your own server? If not, then you have a cross-origin issue (CORS is your answer there).  If it is, then you have some other problem.

Comment: @cale_b thanks, yes I think the issue is CORS because the request is across another domain. If the issue is CORS am I restricted by the 3rd party's config or is it related to my server? Thanks!

Comment: @AlanA Yes, the owners of `somedomain.com` will have to implement CORS response headers to provide your application with permission to make the request. If they haven't and won't offer this, then it won't be possible to make the request client-side with Ajax. You'll probably need a server-side proxy on your own origin to mediate between the client and their server.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ... thanks, is it not significant that I can see the header response in developer tools, I can see the data I want. If my brwoser is receiving this data have I not got it locally?